# How to exclude ip's from Nginx ngx_http_limit_req_module

Tags: nginx

I try to limit ip's connections using on main Nginx config file this:

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=alpha:8m;
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr zone=delta:8m rate=30r/s;
```

and on my domain nginx config file this:

```
limit_conn alpha 10; 
limit_req  zone=delta burst=50 nodelay;
```

And all are working great !!!

But now i want to exclude Cloudflare ip's from this as i am getting a lot of connections from them and i don't want to get them blocked but how?

Cloudflare's ips:

```
192.168.1.0/24 
199.27.128.0/21 
173.245.48.0/20 
103.21.244.0/22 
103.22.200.0/22 
103.31.4.0/22 
141.101.64.0/18 
108.162.192.0/18 
190.93.240.0/20 
188.114.96.0/20 
197.234.240.0/22 
198.41.128.0/17 
162.158.0.0/15 
104.16.0.0/12
```

Comment: If your web site is behind CloudFlare, why are you trying to rate limit IPs at all?

Comment: Some users can find the real ip even if i am behind Cloudflare and is good to limit them....

Comment: You are better of IMO simply blocking them. You can use iptables to [block direct access and allow only cloudfare](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/f4931897f6258e9ad013). If you are using the real-ip module nginx [will not see cloudflare's IPs at all, but that of the proxied client](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-Does-CloudFlare-have-an-IP-module-for-Nginx-).

Comment: But if i add it on Nginx level it will be automatic....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block the IPs, you have to use something like fail2ban.
Just install fail2ban and create a nginx filter file:

```
vim /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-req-limit.conf
```

Add following content in it:

```
[Definition]
failregex = limiting requests, excess:.* by zone.*client: <HOST>
```

Create a new jail config in:

```
vim /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

If you don’t see jail.local, simply run:

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Add following towards end:

```
[nginx-req-limit]

enabled = true
filter = nginx-req-limit
action = iptables-multiport[name=ReqLimit, port="http,https", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/nginx/*error.log
findtime = 600
bantime = 7200
maxretry = 10
```

findtime and maxretry values are important. Together, they decides how often offending IP’s gets banned. If you make these values smaller, IP’s will get banned more often. Tweak as per your need.

After saving both config files, restart fail2ban using:

```
service fail2ban restart
```

You can also use fail2ban-client to find out status of a particular jail using following command:

```
fail2ban-client status nginx-req-limit
```